# Should the box 10 of W2 include dependent care contributions made by an employee?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, form-w-2

My employer has included both the contributions made by them (employer) and by me (employee) in the box 10. As I was not eligible to get the dependent care contributions deducted, I am paying taxes on contributions made by me as well. To me, that feels like a double taxation of the amount that I contributed as I am not deducting it anywhere. Should the box 10 include only the contributions made by the employer?